# Permanently banning user/question?

Tags: discussion, moderation, questions

Recently, we had a user who asked the same anti-semitic, off-topic, and frankly just absurd question multiple times (at least four or five that I have seen, but I would assume that I also missed several question). The user used a different handle for at least some of the questions.

Each time, the question stayed for multiple hours.

In addition to spreading anti-semitism via this platform, this also takes up resources of users trying to refute the absurd claim of the OP each time they ask a new question.

Obviously mods aren't available 24/7, and maybe we do not have enough community members with close/delete vote privileges to react in a timely manner to such questions.

But is there something that moderators can do about this? For example, is it possible to permanently ban a question based on specific keywords (or put it in a moderator-only review queue first)? Or manually ban a user based on IP/user agent/etc (obviously, this can be bypassed, but if such mechanism exists it might be worth a try)? Is there something we as users can do (I assume that we should vote to close, flag, and/or downvote)?

Comment: Latest: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36479/are-there-more-witnesses-for-aliens-than-for-the-holocaust

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We are aware of the situation. I can not, for reasons you can imagine, discuss what steps we are taking about this person. Rest assured that we hear you and we listened to you.

Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 16):

Further to @Sklivvz's response:

Please do flag the post as [**rude or abusive** or **spam**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor) (as appropriate).

Six votes from the community will nuke the question (delete and lock) and ban the IP automatically.

It would be an interesting exercise to look at the data, but I estimate troll and spam posts that manage to get through the automated filtering have a half-life on Skeptics.SE of about an hour - maybe two - which I don't think is too bad.

Comment: The half life is over two hours, based on an analysis at https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4324/require-questions-about-the-holocaust-to-receive-moderator-approval-before-publi