# Please flag trollish questions

Tags: discussion, moderation, flags

Skeptics.SE, along with some other stack exchanges such as history, receives some trolling questions, generally in the form of holocaust denial. They're by users with only 1 reputation, and they're generally don't really ask a question. Rather than merely asking a question about a holocaust denial related claim, the question engages in holocaust denial.

It's possible to flag them as "Rude and Abusive", and if enough users do so, then the post gets deleted automatically. The sooner they get deleted, the better, so please take that approach. Unfortunately, some users seem to be unaware of this: [this post](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39608/is-this-a-holocaust-denial-website), asked 5 hours ago as of now, has three people commenting apart from me, and yet it only has 4 downvotes, whereas each person who flags as "Rude and Abusive" and downvotes would give it 2 downvotes.

For the sake of clarity, I'm not referring to well researched, clearly articulated questions which follow the rules for this stack exchange.

Related but not exactly the same question: [Permanently banning user/question?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/permanently-banning-user-question)

Related question on meta stack exchange: [If a spammer makes many posts using multiple accounts, should all be flagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295819/if-a-spammer-makes-many-posts-using-multiple-accounts-should-all-be-flagged)