# Are we supposed to flag these kinds of questions?

Tags: discussion, support

[This question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/42403/were-the-holocaust-ovens-1000-celsius) is poorly written, and doesn't meet the site requirements for a notable claim, as I understand them. It's also a Holocaust denial question. Should we treat the question just like any other, or take special action because it's a holocaust denial claim?

[This post](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4060/please-flag-trollish-questions) suggests flagging as rude, but I don't see consensus. There does some to be more of an appetite for [this sort of thing](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/20347/has-the-holocaust-been-exaggerated) here than on other SE sites, as discussed in [this meta post](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3843/non-notable-claims-made-only-on-hate-and-or-conspiracy-sites-should-be-deleted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, flag that stuff and let it burn. We routinely ban troll accounts but ultimately the community needs to weed out where we can't reach in time.

Thanks for letting us know.